# Ant Compile Error - NavUtils

Tags: android, ant

Ant doesn't seem to find package: `android.support.v4.app.NavUtils`

**Here's the compiler errors:**

```
C:\Android\MyFirstApp\src\com\example\myfirstapp\DisplayMessageActivity.java:7: error: package  android.support.v4.app does not exist

C:\Android\MyFirstApp\src\com\example\myfirstapp\DisplayMessageActivity.java:22: error: cannot find symbol: NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
```

I have the android directory in sdk with the class files.

**MainActivity.java**

> ```
> package com.example.myfirstapp;
>
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.content.Intent;
> import android.widget.TextView;
> import android.widget.EditText;
> import android.view.MenuItem;
>
> public class MainActivity extends Activity {
>     public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
>     @Override
>     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
>     {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>
>         Intent intent = getIntent();
>         String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
>
>         TextView textView = new TextView(this);
>         textView.setTextSize(40);
>         textView.setText(message);
>
>         setContentView(textView);
>         getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
>     }
> public void sendMessage(View view){
>     Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
>     EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
>     String message = editText.getText().toString();
>     intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
>     startActivity(intent);
> }
> }
> ```

**DisplayMessageActivity.java**

> ```
> package com.example.myfirstapp;
>
> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.os.Bundle;
> import android.view.MenuItem;
> import android.view.View;
> import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
>
> public class DisplayMessageActivity extends Activity {
>     @Override
>     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>         setContentView(R.layout.main);
>         getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
>     }
>     @Override
>     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>         switch (item.getItemId()) {
>         case android.R.id.home:
>             NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
>             return true;
>     }
> return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
> }
> }
> ```

Comment: Did u include `android-sdk/extras/android/compatibility/v4/android-support-v4.jar` in your classpath？

Comment: We had to capitalize From in the second error!?

Answer (score 10):

Coolcfan is (almost) correct.
android.support.v4.NavUtils is not included by default.

Anyway, you need to add the library into the build path. It's located in:

`android-sdk\extras\android\support\v4\android-support-v4.jar`

Once you've done that, it should all work fine.

Note: also make sure that you've defined the parent class in your Manifest using meta-data tags like so:

```
<activity
    android:name=".ChildActivity"
    android:label="@string/childActivity_title" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value=".ParentActivity" >
    </meta-data>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its simple...Search for android-support-v4.jar file. It must be present inside the android-sdk\extras\android\support\v4 folder...
Then copy that jar file and paste it inside your lib directory of your application.
Then compile!
Hope that helps!!!